# output text for pre-specified amount of time in Shiny web application (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I have an output in my server.R file like this:

```
output$thankYouText <- renderText({

    totalActionCount <- as.numeric(input$yes + input$no)

    if (totalActionCount > 0) {

    paste("Thank you. Please see next recommendation.")

            }


  })
```

If someone clicks on either YES or NO buttons the totalActionCount increases and then prints the text. I need this text to now disappear after say 2 seconds, and have this pattern repeat whenever someone clicks the button.

Comment: Maybe you can set `totalActionCount <- 0` in the if statement, and put `invalidateLater(2000)` at the beginning of the `renderText({.})` expression?

Comment: Thanks for the idea...this does not work. I am trying some other vatiations but not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

As @GSee noted you can accomplish this using `invalidateLater`.

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    actionButton("yes", "YES!", icon = icon("thumbs-o-down")),
    actionButton("no", "NO!", icon = icon("thumbs-o-up")),
    textOutput('text')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(tac = 0)
    output$text <- renderText({
      totalActionCount <- as.numeric(input$yes + input$no)
      if (totalActionCount > 0) {
        if(isolate(values$tac < totalActionCount)){
          isolate(values$tac <- totalActionCount)
          invalidateLater(2000, session)
          return(paste("Thank you. Please see next recommendation."))
        }else{
        }
      }
    })
  }
))
```